# Is there an interface in ZF2 that resembles Zend_Registry

Tags: zend-framework2

Is there an interface in `Zend Framework 2` that resembles the `Zend_Registry` component in `Zend Framework 1`. Is the Service Manager the only interface closest? I'm looking for a global registry.

Comment: There isn't a direct equivalent. In ZF2 there's probably a better way to achieve what you want.

Comment: ZF2 allows you to pull services from the service manager and inject them into the classes that need them so there is no need for a global registry.